# Uploading Image to server using UIImagePickerController shows file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed (Swift/iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uiimagepickercontroller, image-uploading

I want to upload the image fetched from photo library in a simulator in my server. But everytime, I am getting this json response :

```
Here the jsonObject is Optional({
    status = "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.";
})
```

I am testing this in a simulator. What type of filetype is not allowed? I don't understand it.

This is my block of code:

```
self.headerImageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

let image1=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

let imgdata : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1!)!

let appDelegate1 = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

UserRoomid=appDelegate1.roomlistid as String


let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"\(liveurl)rooms/image_upload?user_id=\(webservice8)")!)

var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

let contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)

request.addValue(contentType as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")            

let body = NSMutableData()
body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"bklblk.jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(imgdata)


body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


request.HTTPBody = body

let operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)

operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(object: "text/html") as Set<NSObject>

operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess ({

    (operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

    let response : NSString = operation.responseString!

    print("success  is \(response)")

    print("Here the responseObject for success is \(responseObject)")
)}
```

Here is my Server Code:

```
public function image_upload()
{
    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'] = 'image/png';
    $id = $this->input->get('user_id');

    $file_element_name = 'uploadedfile';

    $this->path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images/users/');
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file_element_name = 'uploadedfile';

    if ($status != "error")    
    {
        if(!is_dir($this->path.'/'.$id))
        {
            mkdir($this->path.'/'.$id, 0777, true);
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id;

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
        $config['file_name'] = 'userpic.jpg';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)){
            $status = 'error';  
            $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('','');
            $data = "";
            echo '[{"status":"'.$msg.'"}]'; 
        }
        else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $image = base_url().'/images/'.$id.'/userpic_thumb.jpg';
            $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config1['source_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic.jpg';
            $config1['new_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic_thumb.jpg';
            $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config1['width'] = 107;
            $config1['height'] = 78;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);

            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
            {
                $resize = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
            //$image = base_url().'/images/'.$id.'/pic_file.jpg'; 
    $image = base_url().'images/users/'.$id.'/userpic_profile.jpg';
            $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config2['source_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic.jpg';
            $config2['new_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic_profile.jpg';
            $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config2['width'] = 209;
            $config2['height'] = 209;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
            {
                $resize = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
            //$image = base_url().'/images/'.$id.'/pic_home.jpg';
    $image = base_url().'images/users/'.$id.'/userpic_home.jpg';
            $config3['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config3['source_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic.jpg';
            $config3['new_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/users/'.$id.'/userpic_home.jpg';
            $config3['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config3['width'] = 320;
            $config3['height'] = 320;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);

            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
            {
                $resize = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $resize = base_url().'images/users/'.$id.'/userpic.jpg';
            //$resize = base_url().'images/'.$id.'/pic.jpg';   

            echo '[{"image":"'.$image.'","resize":"'.$resize.'"}]';exit;

        }

        @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show server code also?

Comment: Please Check .. I have edited the question.

Comment: aa lot of code an i am not understand $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'] = 'image/png';

Comment: I don't understand php too :(

Comment: But, tell me one thing. How do we specify allowed file type? Because the error that I am getting now is : "You have not specified any allowed file types."

Answer (score 0):

try to use as server code

```
if(isset($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
                $file = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
                if (move_uploaded_file($file, ROOT_DIRECTORY.'../../../../images/driver_'.$driver->id.'.jpg')) {
       //success
                }
            }
```

Comment: actually the issue was with the allowed file type in php server, they had allowed jpg,jpeg,png format in the server side. However, the image that was being uploaded from my end was jpg but the type format was rejected. Now, when I told the backend guys to correct it, they changed the allowed type to everything and the problem was solved ;/